# python - how can I display a image from web?

Tags: python

I'm using Python to make a "web album viewer", but I meet some problem.

I use Tkinter to write GUI, urllib2 to fetch the image from web, PIL to handle the image

So the code is like this:

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
response = urllib2.urlopen(a_pic_url)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(response.read()))
label = Label(frame, image = photo)
label.pack()
```

it fails, and throws the following error message:

```
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be (encoded string without NULL bytes), not str
```

How can I overcome this?

Thanks, and I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I change "ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(response.read()))" to "ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(response))", but it still failed: AttributeErrpr: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'

Answer (score 4):

`Image.open` takes a filename or a file object, not a `str` which is what is returned by `read`.

Either save the image to a file then open that, or use `Image.open(response)`, to use it directly on the file-like objected returned by `urlopen`.

**Edit:** This should work if you're having trouble with the `urlopen` object:

```
try:
    from io import BytesIO
except ImportError:
    from cStringIO import StringIO as BytesIO #works on on old versions of Python

response = urllib2.urlopen(a_pic_url)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=BytesIO(response.read()))
```

Comment: Gah!  Seven goldurn seconds ahead of me.

Comment: I change "ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(response.read()))" to "ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(response))", but still fail: AttributeErrpr: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but it still failed: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: I fixed it now, I just left out part of a line.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your English.  There's a slight error in your code.  It should be:

```
 photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(response))
```

The `.read()` part was messing with you.

Comment: Upboats all around, 7 seconds notwithstanding.

Comment: As noted in the comment to my question, this doesn't actually work -- there is not `seek` method on the not-really-so-filelike-object returned by `urlopen`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when using `Image.open()` PIL waits for a filename, and what you gave is the content of the image file. Try to save the image before :

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
response = urllib2.urlopen(a_pic_url)
open(image_file_name, "wb+").write(response.read())
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=image_file_name)
label = Label(frame, image = photo)
label.pack()
```

Comment: `Image.open` can also take a file-like object, not just a filename.

Comment: @agf : I'm asking myself if PhotoImage could not handle directly the response also...

Comment: Good thought, I've used this basic idea (with a `BytesIO` instead of a real file) in my updated answer.